# Found an NSZombie in my app... now what?

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, malloc, nsinvocation

I have a subclass of NSManagedObject with a few "integer 32" attributes that are really enums. These enums are defined in my model's .h file like this:

```
typedef enum {
    AMOwningCompanyACME,
    AMOwningCompanyABC,
    AMOwningCompanyOther
} AMOwningCompany;
```

I need to show a table view that displays the value of each attribute of this custom object, so for each enum I have a method that looks like this to return string values:

```
-(NSArray*)stringsForAMOwningCompany
{
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ACME Co.", @"ABC Co.", @"Other", nil];
}
```

In my table view, I iterate through the attributes of my `NSManagedObject` (using `NSEntityDescription`'s `attributesByName` and for each attribute I call a helper method that calls the appropriate "stringsFor" method to return the strings for that particular attribute:

```
-(NSArray*)getStringsArrayForAttribute:(NSString*)attributeName
{
    SEL methodSelector = NSSelectorFromString([self methodNameForAttributeNamed:attributeName]);
    NSInvocation* invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[[AMProperty class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:methodSelector]];
    [invocation setSelector:methodSelector];
    [invocation setTarget:self.editingPole];
    [invocation invoke];

    NSArray* returnValue = nil;
    [invocation getReturnValue:&returnValue];

    return returnValue;
}
```

My table view's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` looks like this:

```
...
NSString* itemName = self.tableData[indexPath.row];
NSAttributeDescription* desc = itemAttributes[itemName];

NSString* cellIdentifier = [self cellIdentifierForAttribute:desc]; // checks the attribute type and returns a different custom cell identifier accordingly
if ([cellIdentifier isEqualToString:@"enumCell"])
{
    // dequeue cell, customize it
    UITableViewCell* enumCell = ...
    ...
    NSArray* stringValues = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self getStringArrayForAttribute:itemName]];
    int currentValue = [(NSNumber*)[self.editingPole valueForKey:itemName] intValue];
    enumCell.detailTextLabel.text = (NSString*)stringValues[currentValue];
    return enumCell;
}
...
```

For only one of the attributes, I keep getting a crash on the `NSInvocation`'s return array:

```
-[__NSArrayI release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x856a4b0
```

Using the Zombies Profiler, I see:

[image: Instruments Screenshot]

I am using ARC. How can I debug this further?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into a very similar problem myself recently and it took me a while to figure out what I was doing wrong. An extra release is being issued here -- because your pointer `returnValue` is `__strong` (the default), ARC believes that the object is owned via that pointer, but that's not the case.

`-[NSInvocation getReturnValue:]` doesn't take ownership of it, and the "assignment" via the pointer's address bypasses the `objc_storeStrong()` that ARC would normally use.

The solution is simple: mark the pointer as `__unsafe_unretained`. This is the truth; the object is not retained via this pointer (as it would if it were `__strong`), and ARC must not release it here.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you. I never fully understood memory management in Objective-C, and with ARC, I thought I didn't need to worry either. Clearly not true ;)

Comment: Usually you don't, but passing objects through `void *` is sort of the lunatic fringe.